# Change color shape and edit legend in R ggplot2 object

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to modify a ggplot2 object where I took an object and used the scale_colour_manual and scale_shape_manual to change the colors and shapes. However, now I'd like to only show the top two items in the legend.

As you can see in the code, I changed the first and third shapes to match each other and now the third is redundant but I still want that underlying data within the plot. The desired result would be plot2 but without the third value within the legend but with the data left within the plot.

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg, group=as.factor(cyl))) +
  geom_point(aes(shape=as.factor(cyl), color=as.factor(cyl)))

plot <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg, group=as.factor(cyl))) +
        geom_point(aes(shape=as.factor(cyl), color=as.factor(cyl)))

plot2 <- plot +
         scale_colour_manual(values = c('#999999', '#999999','#999999')) +   
         scale_shape_manual(values = c(0, 1, 0))

plot2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `breaks = ...` to `scale_colour_manual` and `scale_shape_manual` should do it

```r
plot3 <- plot +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c('#999999', '#999999','#999999'), 
                      breaks = c('4', '6')) +   
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(0, 1, 0), 
                     breaks = c('4', '6'))

# https://github.com/thomasp85/patchwork
# install.packages("devtools", dependencies = TRUE)
# devtools::install_github("thomasp85/patchwork")
library(patchwork)
plot2 + plot3 +
  plot_layout(ncol = 2)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-04-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1.9000)</sup>